# Django views.py CreateView

Tags: python, django

I'm currently doing my second Django project and I want to know something about views.py

in my first project I had classes that had the field:

*model = 'name model'*
or
*form_class = 'name form'*

some of them had both
and now in my second project I have class that has:

*form_class = forms.UserCreateForm*

How should I know which one should I use - from forms or from models and why this time Django won't let me do:
  *form_class = UserCreateForm* 
and needs this 'forms.'

Answer (score 1):

I think you have to take back the bases of Django.

[What's the best way to start learning django?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4048973/whats-the-best-way-to-start-learning-django)

You have to learn what is the difference between a model, a view, a form and a template.

Comment: I just want to know why with this UserCreateForm which is from django.contrib.auth.forms - UserCreationForm

i need to say forms. 

and with the ordinary forms i dont need to do it

Answer (score 1):

You can import the form itself.

```
from django.contrib.auth.forms import UserCreationForm 

class MyCreateView(CreateView):
   form_class = UserCreationForm
```

Or you can import the `forms` module, in which case you need to use `forms.UserCreationForm`.

```
from django.contrib.auth import forms

class MyCreateView(CreateView):
   form_class = forms.UserCreationForm
```

Personally, I think the first is clearer. It is very common to do `from django import forms`, which would clash with the second import. You could avoid this clash by importing it as `auth_forms`:

```
from django.contrib.auth import forms as auth_forms

class MyCreateView(CreateView):
   form_class = auth_forms.UserCreationForm
```